# how to pass two text box value to a href link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to dynamically pass input values to href, but unable to pass them as I expect. This is what I tried -

```
<a target="_blank" href="" 
onclick="this.href='https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin='   
                      +document.getElementById('lon3').value,+document.getElementById('lat3').value
                      &destination=2.183180,102.261803">map</a>
```

how can I pass the value successfully?

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing happen* ?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use a form?

Comment: when i click the link no response to that particular website

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: ... .value,+document. ...  remove the ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is a good practice to write your script in a function & call it on HTML tags.
>   So, here's your working demonstration with your scenario -

```js
function changeUrl() {
  let lattitude = document.getElementById('lat3').value;
  let longitude = document.getElementById('lon3').value;
  let target = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
  let seperator = encodeURI(",");
  let href = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=' + lattitude + seperator + longitude + '&destination=2.183180,102.261803';
  target.href = href;
  console.log(target.href);
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="" onclick="changeUrl()" id="myAnchor">map</a>
                      
<input type="text" value="1234.5678" id="lon3">
<input type="text" value="0567.1211" id="lat3">
```

***Note*** that, it won't work as expected here on SO snippet, so Check console to see the change! **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ek2tx08/4/)**'s the jsfiddle snippet for a properly working demo

Comment: let href = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=' + lattitude + seperator + longitude + '&destination='+ lattitude + seperator + longitude';

Comment: why like this cannot run

Comment: It seems that SO doesn't allow external redirects from snippets

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically modify the `href` onclick and expect the redirect.

You can however use the window.location = `//your URL here`

```
<a target="_blank" href="#" onclick="window.location = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=' + document.getElementById('lon3').value + ',' + document.getElementById('lat3').value + '&destination=2.183180,102.261803';">map</a>
```

Comment: We can dynamically modify the href onclick, it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the onclick event on your link and remove the default behaviour, then you can add your custom redirection like :

```js
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var lon3 = document.getElementById('lon3').value; 
    var lat3 = document.getElementById('lat3').value;
    window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=" + lon3 + lat3 +"&destination=2.183180,102.261803", '_blank');
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#">map</a>

<input type="hidden" id="lon3" value="somevalue">
<input type="hidden" id="lat3" value="somevalue">
```